# ASP.NET inline code within an inline style tag.

Tags: asp.net, styles, inline

ok, I'm trying to figure out how to put some data into an inline style.
I want to read from a data source and build the URL for a background image of a

```
<li style="background-image: url(http://www.domain.com/images/NameFromDataID.jpg);"></li>
```

I have tried to insert this inline code to insert the filename.

```
<%# "commonName" + Eval("ID") + ".jpg" %>
```

but it doesn't work...  I have an asp:ListView with many other things in it working, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the data into the li style...

maybe I should be trying to build the entire style and then attach it to the li?

Comment: <%# "commonName" + Eval("ID") + ".jpg" %>, How do you define commonName?

Comment: it's just some text i'm adding to all file names I'm building from the data.  rather than store the file names in the data I figured I would build them. maybe including the file path actually...

Comment: I have not had luck with style="background-image: url(<%# anything %>);"

Comment: Have you checked the string constructed with this url(<%# anything %>);? what is the final rendered url, check and post. That should give you a hint to the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're using Databind syntax, you need to enclose the entire attribute value inside the brackets.

```
 style='<%# "background-image: url(" + Eval("ID") + ".jpg)" %>'
```

Comment: I guess there is only the debate about single or double quotes being valid for tag attributes but I don't know that it's a big deal... (in reality)